# geometric program maximizing using Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality

Tags: optimization, geometric-programming

Maximize $xy^2z^3$ subject to $x^3+y^2+z = 39$ and $x,y,z > 0$.

I have that $39 = x^3 + y^2 + z = ..$

I am unsure what value I should use for $\delta_i$ in each coefficient when using the A-G inequality.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$39=x^3+3(y^2/3)+9(z/9)\ge 13\sqrt[13]{x^3y^6z^9/3^{21}}$$

Comment: so would it become $13 (\frac{xy^2z^3}{3^{7}})^{1/10}$ or is my math wrong?

Comment: The exponent is wrong, its $3/13$, not $1/10$. Better to note that $\implies 3^{13/3+7}\ge xy^2z^3$ and establish equality is possible when $x^3=y^2/3=z/9=3$

Comment: @Macavity: what inequality did you apply? It seems to be not the usual average mean >= geometric mean...

Comment: @chip it is the usual AM GM for $13$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a Lagrangian?
The problem can be written as
$$\text{max} \ xy^2z^3+\lambda(39-x^3-y^2-z)$$
Taking first order conditions, you get that
$$df/dx=y^2z^2-3x^2\lambda=0$$
$$df/dy=2xyz^3-2y\lambda=0$$
$$df/dz=3xy^2z^2-\lambda=0$$
From here, you can see that 
$$\lambda=3xy^2z^2$$
Plugging this into the two other equations, you get
$$y^2z^3-3x^2(3xy^2z^2)=0$$
$$2xyz^3-2y(3xy^2z^2)=0$$
Getting rid of redundant variables, you get the following system of equations
$$z=9x^3$$
$$3y^2=z$$
$$39=x^3+y^2+z$$
You can easily solve this system of equations to get the optimal values of $x,y,z$.